# Lorentz Violation in Condensed Matter Systems

Tags: special-relativity, condensed-matter, superconductivity, topological-insulators

I have heard from a few different sources that certain condensed matter systems like topological superconductors and insulators violate Lorentz invariance. Can someone explain how that happens?

Comment: It could be useful for you to read up on spontaneous symmetry breaking to understand how even though a theory can have a symmetry, a particular background can break that symmetry. In condensed matter, the underlying model IS Lorentz invariant, but the background lattice on which the system is defined (in general, it may not be a lattice) breaks the symmetry. Consequently, the physics of any fluctuations on top of that lattice will not be Lorent invariant.

Comment: AFAIK when there's talk about topological systems breaking Lorentz invariance, you talk about systems, whose low energy regime looks like ultrarelativistic particles (this is e.g. the case semimetals with Dirac cones and derived systems). It is this approximate symmetry, that formally looks like Lorentz invariance, which is then broken.

Answer (score 6):

When we study the electronic states of crystalline solids, we usually treat the crystal structure as a static background, and add dynamical effects like lattice vibrations as perturbations. This is the [Born-Oppenheimer approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born%E2%80%93Oppenheimer_approximation), which essentially assumes that the electronic states and states of the lattice can be understood independently.

In that context, the presence of the (non-dynamical) background lattice manifestly breaks Lorentz symmetry in a fairly obvious way. The fact that electronic states are not shackled by Lorentz symmetry means that a vastly wider array of phenomena are possible than in the case of the Minkowski vacuum. This is partly why I find condensed matter so enjoyable.

From a fundamental perspective, yes - if you include the full dynamics of the lattice and treat everything relativistically, then Lorentz invariance would be recovered. However, what you'll find (if you haven't already) is that treating everything at that level is completely untenable even for systems of a few particles, to say nothing of an entire crystal. Sacrificing Lorentz invariance is often necessary to obtain models which you can actually get anything out of in the first place (and, as I say, I see this as a bonus, not an issue to overcome).

If you're interested in this viewpoint, it was very eloquently discussed by Laughlin in his book [A Different Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Different_Universe).

Answer (score 3):

For context, you're definitely referring to [your earlier post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/767443/violation-of-lorentz-invariance/767447#767447).

To clarify, nobody was saying that there are real Lorentz violations in condensed matter systems. We were saying that in some systems (like condensed matter), we don't bother accounting for relativistic effects. That's all there is to it. We're not saying that we're observing physics that displays Lorentz violations, but rather that we don't feel the need to account for relativity in our models for said systems.

Comment: If you read the comments by Prahar under my question in the previous post, you will see that he said that the reply given by the AI bot is correct. I did some search of my own on the internet and I found sources saying that there are indeed instances of Lorentz violation in certain settings, one of them being cond-mat systems. I'd suggest you to read this article: https://physicsworld.com/a/breaking-lorentz-symmetry/

Comment: Here's another interesting post tangentially related to this topic: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/54279/spontaneous-breaking-of-lorentz-invariance-in-gauge-theories

Comment: There is work being conducted that questions if Lorentz invariance holds on the fundamental level, but there is, at this time, no experimental or observational evidence that suggests the existence of Lorentz violations. I assure you that anyone who at this time states there have been Lorentz violations found is either misinformed or outright lying to you. The discovery of such violations would have a massive impact on a multitude of fields within physics and after verification would result in the very next Nobel prize being awarded for that work.

Comment: I understand that there is no experimental proof for the violation of Lorentz symmetry at the fundamental level. But the violation of Lorentz invariance in condensed-matter systems is not simply because we are observing them at non-relativistic velocities. The explanation is something else, apparently a lattice background that acts as an absolute reference frame as opposed to an inertial reference frame, which causes the violation. That is what I am trying to understand.

Comment: Personal opinions aside, Sabbine Hossenfelder has [a good article on precisely this](https://backreaction.blogspot.com/2016/04/dear-dr-b-why-is-lorentz-invariance-in.html).

Comment: @LoganJ.Fisher - There is no Lorentz violation in the UV (as far as we know). But there could be Lorentz violations in the IR depending on what background the low energy theory is in. This is what happens in condensed matter systems.

Comment: Of course in the non relativistic regime you find that relativity doesn't work. That's the definition of non relativistic regime. Also $F=ma$ violates Lorentz invariance, by definition, but this doesn't mean Lorentz invariance is broken by nature. Is broken by human approximations

Comment: Condensed matter crystals break also rotation invariance and continuos translational invariance, but that doesn't mean that nature break them. Human approximation does